# Downloading data from smartbands (e.g. Xiaomi Mi Band 5)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is there any way or SDK that would allow my Android application to connect to the wristbands and download data from them, such as heart rate, number of steps or sleep? I'm trying to make my own fit application that will be able to collect such data. I want to connect to, for example, Mi Band 5 in the simplest way, without the need to use shell commands

I tried to download the sdk https://github.com/pangliang/miband-sdk-android however gradle had trouble downloading this sdk. I downloaded the SDK from Xiaomi, but due to the lack of documentation, it was difficult to do anything. I tried to detect the band via BluetoothGATT in the test Android application, but it crashed when launched